# Multiple Just data constructors to wrap a value

Tags: haskell

Is `Just 5` same as `Just (Just 5)`. Theoretically, i am sure the answer is no but does in real life, do we use values like `Just (Just (Just ..... (Just 5)))`

At least one example i encountered is in [real world haskell](https://github.com/cyga/real-world-haskell/blob/master/ch15/MovieReview.hs#L34) as,

```
maybeReview alist = do
title <- lookup1 "title" alist
return (MovieReview title)'

lookup1 key alist = case lookup key alist of
                      Just (Just s@(_:_)) -> Just s
                      _ -> Nothing
```

Why do we need the outer `Just` data constructor in this line,

```
Just (Just s@(_:_)) -> Just s
```

Comment: Note: to convert a `Just (Just x)` to a `Just x` you can use the [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) function. It works with any monad, not just `Maybe`.

Comment: "Why do we need the outer `Just`?" Because there are two distinct kinds of failures: either we can fail to find the key, or we can succeed in finding the key but discover that there's no associated value. To model the two distinct kinds of failure, we use two levels of `Maybe`. (Other models are certainly possible, including ones which throw away information about which kind of failure we encountered.)

Answer (score 4):

`Just 5` has type `Maybe Int`, and `Just (Just 5)` has type `Maybe (Maybe Int)`  The values are of different types.

There's not a lot of differrence between`Maybe a` and `Maybe (Maybe a)`.  `Just x` is very similar to `Just (Just x)`, and `Nothing :: Maybe a` is very similar to `Nothing :: Maybe (Maybe a)`.  The only real difference is the existence of `Just Nothing`, which has no comparable value in `Maybe a`.

If you consider type `a` to have cardinality of N (there are N possible values of type `a`), then `Maybe a` has cardinality of N+1, with N values like `Just x` and one value of `Nothing`. So `Maybe (Maybe a)` has a cardinality of N+2.